# perlbrew command not found

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I installed perlbrew on Linux backtrack on my virtual machine. and I have perl 5.10.1 installed on my backtrack. but when I write perlbrew command in the terminal it shows the following message:
perlbrew: command not found

What is wrong with my system?

Comment: @ruakh, `perlbrew` is a shell function, not an executable.

Comment: @ikegami, actually it's both.  The shell function handles the environment variable changing, but the executable prints out what the environment should look like.

Comment: @cjm, Yeah, but it's the shell function that's executed by the user and would result in that error. It's not relevant that there should also exist an executable with the same name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you installed `perlbrew`, you were instructed to add something like

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
```

to your shell startup script (`.bashrc`). It appears that you did not do this, or that you did not restart your shell after doing this.

Comment: when I copy code in ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc and paste it into a ~/.bash_profile and restarted the virtual machine, it worked. It was instructed but I didn't pay much attention.

Comment: Don't copy the code; that will break upgrades. Use `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` instead.

Comment: thanks.perhaps I misunderstood the instructions. It is the instructions:

Comment: perlbrew is installed: ~/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew

perlbrew root (~/perl5/perlbrew) is initialized.

Append the following piece of code to the end of your ~/.bash_profile and start a
new shell, perlbrew should be up and fully functional from there:

    source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

Simply run `perlbrew` for usage details.

Comment: "The following piece of code" is `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc`, not the contents of some file.

Comment: You didn't miss anything. It's apparently a step they forgot to mention on the official instructions = / (http://perlbrew.pl/)

Answer (score 2):

The standard `sudo apt install perlbrew` on a fresh Ubuntu18 install appears to be borken (and Ubuntu20 too if my memory isn't malfunctioning). And has been so for some time. I couldn't get it to work even if I appended `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` to ~/.bash_profile and/or ~/.bashrc and started a new bash. And also did `perlbrew init`.

What eventually worked for me is `curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash` taken from https://perlbrew.pl/ After this `which perlbrew` shows the correct `/home/me/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew` instead of `/usr/bin/perlbrew`. And now I can see the whole list of available perl5 versions with `perlbrew available`.