# how to uninstall perlbrew from macbook

Tags: perl, uninstallation, perlbrew

I have few modules associated with it. However when I try to switch from system perl to perlbrew it displays

> -sh: perlbrew: command not found

however in the directory I have,

> bin        lib        man         perlbrew

It has been almost over a year since I used perl and perlbrew and I am not able to figure it out how I did it the last time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to check your env vars to make sure if there is a path to perlbrew home and also check this answer might be helpful [perlbrew command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084323/perlbrew-command-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

1. From the login script, delete the line

   ```
   source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
   ```
2. Delete the `perlbrew` directory

   ```
   rm -rf ~/perl5/perlbrew
   ```

That assumes you installed `perlbrew` in its default location. If not, env var `$PERLBREW_ROOT` should indicate to where it's installed.

---

If instead you'd rather fix the problem,

1. Move `~/perl5/perlbrew/perls` to somewhere safe.
2. Delete `~/perl5/perlbrew`.
3. Reinstall `perlbrew`.
4. Restore the `perls` directory.